# Zoom function Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow, marker

I've created a button inside my info window that needs to pan to the marker and then zoom in but I can't get it to work. Below is my Zoom function

```
function Zoom(){
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    map.panTo(marker.position);
    map.setZoom(18);
});
```

and this the function that creates the marker and fills the info window with the html below.

```html
function createMarker(latlng, name, woonplaats, prijs, perceelop, woonop, address) {
  var html ="<a href="+address+">"+"<b>"+name+"</b></a> <br/>" 
            + woonplaats +"</br>" + woonop + "/ " + perceelop + "</br>" + "€ " + prijs + 
            "</br><input id='zoombutton' type='button' onclick='Zoom()' value='Zoom in' />" 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

If I remove the panTo function it does Zoom in, but it doesn't pan to the marker so it zooms in in a totally different place. I also tried to make the button invisible if the zoom level is 18 or higher but with no result.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marker.position` is an undocumented parameter (if it exists).  Use `marker.getPosition()` to get the marker's position.

```
function Zoom(){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(18);
  }); 
// ??
}
```

I get a javascript error with your code though: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`

- not sure why you are adding a click listener to `marker` in the button onclick function
- you will need to keep references to all your markers (assuming there is more than one)

```
// in the global scope:
var markers = [];

function Zoom(markerNum) {
  // markerNum is the index of this marker in the markers array
  map.panTo(markers[markerNum].getPosition());
  map.setZoom(18);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5syf969y/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  createMarker(map.getCenter(), "Palo Alto");
  createMarker({
    lat: 37.42410599999999,
    lng: -122.1660756
  }, "Stanford");
}

function createMarker(latlng, name) {
  var html = name + "</br><input id='zoombutton' type='button' onclick='Zoom(" + markers.length + ")' value='Zoom in' />"
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function Zoom(markerNum) {
  map.panTo(markers[markerNum].getPosition());
  map.setZoom(18);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```