# How to control zoom level in Google Maps according to places

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing Google Maps with places API in my Application. I need that ,whenever user types the place in edit text , the map to animate to that particular place. I have implemented it and its working fine. The issue is if I am not able to control zoom level according to the place mentioned in AutocompleteTextView, for eg, if its a exact address , I want to zoom in more, if its a state, the zoom should differ , also when its a country, it should zoom out accordingly.

I get the lat long as :

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);

            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            place.getPlaceTypes();

            Log.d("Result Callback Hit", "Success");

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(),10));

        }
    };
```

Comment: Do you have latitude and longitudes?

Comment: Follow the link for simple implementation 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721896/zoom-function-google-maps

Comment: @YasirTahir : yes i have latitude, longitude

Comment: @surajrawat : its a different  problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this method to move the camera to any point on the Map

With animation:

```
private void moveToSelectedArea(LatLng position) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        int ZOOM_LEVEL = 14;
        // In your case, if you want to apply different zoom for different type, make a switch case based on type and set the zoom value
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, ZOOM_LEVEL));
    }
}
```

Without animation:

```
private void moveToSelectedArea(LatLng position) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        int ZOOM_LEVEL = 14;
        // In your case, if you want to apply different zoom for different type, make a switch case based on type and set the zoom value
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, ZOOM_LEVEL));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get the type?

Comment: How you're converting typed address into latitude and longitude? Do you have android.location.Address?

Comment: What does place.getPlaceTypes(); returns? You can use this in order to differentiate. Have a look at this. You can use country, locality for city name and sublocality for area within city https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place#constant-summary